# Bind to a service - call back when bind has been successfully - Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I've come to a point where I don't know an elegant way to do this.

Let's say I've a `Fragment`, named `FragmentA`, and a `Service` named `BackupService`

On `FragmentA` I bound it to the `BackupService` using:

```
private ServiceConnection backupServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        backupBoundService = binder.getService();
        isBound = true;
        // How to let the fragment know this has happened?
        // Use an eventBus? EventBus.getDefault().post(backupBoundService); ?
        Log.d(TAG, "On Service Connected -> Yup!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        isBound = false;
    }
};
```

And:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(), BackupsService.class);
ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().bindService(intent, backupServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); // Using application context
```

Now I know the binding is an `asynchronous` task and here is where my question comes in.

I came up with the idea of using an `EventBus` but I don't find it elegant as the fragment would be posting the object (in this case `backupBoundService`), referencing the service, and at the same time would be listening/receiving the event from the bus, eg, would be the same fragment posting and receiving the event (posting to himself).

Is there an elegant way to get a reference for the running service when the fragment is bounded to it? I'm quite sure there's a pattern for this case but I've been googling and searching here to no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use eventbus or you can create simple call back methods using Interfcae for you requirement.

If you don't have idea  to create call backs using interface then look this piece of code.
It is same like eventbus :)

```
  // The callback interface
  interface MyCallback {
  void callbackCall();
  }

 // The class that takes the callback
 class Worker {
 MyCallback callback;

  void onEvent() {
  callback.callbackCall();
  }
  public void setCallBack(MyCallback callback)
     this.callback=callback;
  }
 /////////////////////////////
class Callback implements MyCallback {

  ....
 Worker worker= new Worker()
 Worker.setCallback(this);      
 .. .

  void callbackCall() {
  // callback code goes here
  //onEvent this method will execute
 }

}
```

Hope this will helpful. 
Good luck :)

Comment: That would be the same, receive a callback, for a callback I would keep using the traditional way of waiting for the `onServiceConnected` callback